# Pressing P leaves Blender frozen, how to get undo?

Tags: interface

[image]

I was rigging a foot to a skeleton when I meant to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, I pressed <kbd>P</kbd>. Nothing happened so I then clicked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and my entire skeleton and avatar turned white. My mouse does not show up inside the Blender screen and I don't want to close it and start over. I did save but I'll still lose quite a bit of work.

Is there a button I have pushed that can be undone via the keyboard?

Comment: I figured out how to fix it!

I noticed that I could barely put my mouse along the edge as if I wanted to adjust the size of the screen. When I clicked it, I shrunk the screen in some and the black area in the picture above showed my blender tools once more and my avatar was back in normal object mode!

I am not sure if it was simply a blip in the program or if P and then Ctrl P does something but it's solved.

Comment: Should I delete this question? It said I could be banned if I delete too many questions. I didn't see that other question when I searched through similar questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this happened when you pressed <kbd>P</kbd>, you've started the [Game Engine](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine) preview. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return back to your normal view.

Comment: Thank you! I tried Esc. and it acted as if the program had frozen up. I appreciate the reply!